# Form Intake & Mass assignment in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm developing a Laravel Web Application that involves storing lots of data in the database so far I've been using the regular Laravel Store as follows partially because I prefer this way & partially because I may need to use the Model Events in the future(Model Events don't fire in case of Mass Assignment):

```
$product = new Product;
$product->name = "EXT";
// MANY MORE FIELDS
$product->save();
```

But I've read somewhere that It's not a good practice to do it this way instead use the Mass assignment as that is faster & more efficient.

Is that correct? Should I keep using the method I'm using or should I switch to Mass Assignment/Update?

PS: I'm aware that the security risks from Mass Assignment can be averted by $gaurded & $fillable.

Comment: Who said that model events don't fire in case of mass assignment?

Comment: @apokryfos Laravel documentation @ https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#updates - Alert right below "Mass Updates"

Comment: Mass **updates** don't trigger saved and updated. Mass assignments are fine. If you find yourself needing to do mass updates and also listen for events then you probably will need to query for the models first and then do a save on each one. (this will cover most actual use cases because it's not than common to blanket update many models except for the case of scheduled updates)

Comment: @apokryfos I see. Thanks. My question remains though, Are mass updates/assignment a better way to update/insert compared to what I am using? If so is there any reason other than shorter code?

Comment: Yes mass assignment in conjuction with `$fillable` is better because you can just design your form request to directly go to the constructor

Comment: @Zakriya Bilal, if you look at the source of [\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::create($attributes)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L752), it does the same thing what you did but gets attribute list from `$fillable` or `$guarded`, aka mass-assignment protection.

Comment: @MustafaAkçakaya Right, So that pretty much means there is no problem with doing it the way I am doing it?

Comment: @Zakriya Bilal Yes, of course. It's a matter of choice.

Comment: @MustafaAkçakaya Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should check Laravel documentation,

[Laravel Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment)

There is no information about performance.

Then, I think Mass Assignment is more useful than the others. Because you don't need to write each value on code. You just should set `fillable` or `guard` variables for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

In Model just set `protected $fillable=[];` and `protected $guarded=[];` to empty array and use whatever you want to use, either mass assignment or eloquent or query builder.